# Escape for folder Exists and Create purposes

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\" + reader1.GetString(ColIndex1) + @"\" + reader1.GetString(ColIndex2) + @"\" + reader1.GetString(ColIndex3)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\" + reader1.GetString(ColIndex1) + @"\" + reader1.GetString(ColIndex2) + @"\" + reader1.GetString(ColIndex3));
}
```

How do I escape the values so it can correctly check if folders exist and create them if needed?

For example, at the moment, if ColIndex2 contains text which includes the following characters:

```
\/:*?"<>|
```

The code does not create the folders properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to check if subdirectories exist . `Directory.CreateDirectory` will create all subdirectories that you need. For more information check the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.100).aspx).

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path.

Moreover instead of concatening your strings with `@"\"`, the safer way is to use `Path.Combine`. E.g :

```
String yourFullPath = Path.Combine(
      @"C:\", 
      reader1.GetString(ColIndex1),  
      reader1.GetString(ColIndex2), 
      reader1.GetString(ColIndex3)); 

// following will do nothing if yourFullPath already exists
Directory.CreateDirectory(yourFullPath) ;
```

Finally, I've tried this sample with a `/` character :

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(@"c:\", @"a/b\c")) ;
```

And it's creating all the folders `a`, `b` and `c`.

**EDIT**

If you want to removeInvalidcharPath. [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you to do so :

```
char [] allInvalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(); 
string yourPathWithoutInvalidChars = new string(yourFullPath.ToCharArray().Where(c => !allInvalidChars.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks.  This has reduced the code a lot, but doesn't seem to deal with all the following characters `\/:*?"<>|`.